# GNU make: How to force an intermediate dependency to be made when it doesn't exist

Tags: makefile

There are three types of files. For convenience lets call them type1 (*.1 files), type2 (*.2 files) and type3 (*.3 files). Type2 is made from type1 by running a certain command; type3 is made from type2 by running a certain other command.

Type2 files age and become invalid, therefore are deleted from time to time.

I have rules like:

```
%.2 : %.1
    cmd1 $< -o $@

%.3 : %.2
    cmd2 $< > $@
```

Now if xyz.1 and xyz.3 exist (xyz.1 is *not newer than* xyz.3), and xyz.2 has been deleted, running `make xyz.3` simply says that everything is up-to-date, and nothing needs to be done.

If I `touch xyz.1` then run `make`, everything works as expected.

I **need** `make xyz.3` to first create the type2 file, then re-create the type3 file. Is there any way to do this?

Versions:

- GNU make 3.81
- OS X 10.9.1
- GNU bash 3.2.51

**Update 1:** Made it clearer that pattern rules are being used (thanks for pointing that out, @Louis), and that more than one file of each type exists.

Comment: make works this way because it's common to delete intermediate files, e.g. `.c -> .o -> .exe`. You should be able to delete the `.o` files, and don't need to regenerate them if none of the `.c` have changed.

Comment: @Barmar I am not talking about .c, .o and .exe files. I have to have both type2 and type3 files -- this is specific to my problem space (that's why I didn't specify the actual file types).

Comment: I understand. I'm just trying to help you understand the rationale of the current design.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that, I'd forgotten. Been almost a decade since I last used make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Problem

The problem is due to the use of patterns:

```
all: foo.3

%.2: %.1
    touch $@

%.3: %.2
    touch $@
```

In this case `make foo.3; rm foo.2; make foo.3` will *not* result in `foo.2` and `foo.3` being remade. In fact, with the `Makefile` above `make` will by itself delete `foo.2` after it creates `foo.3` because `foo.2` is an intermediate target and that's what `make` does with intermediate targets. (See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules).)

#### The Solution

The solution is simple, list `foo.2` as an explicit target:

```
all: foo.3

foo.2: %.2: %.1
    touch $@

%.3: %.2
    touch $@
```

By having `foo.2` listed explicitly, it is no longer considered intermediate. The syntax used above is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html). Presumably there are more than one file to which the rule applies so a more general solution would be:

```
# Get all files that end in `.1` from the filesystem.
type1_files:=$(wildcard *.1)

# For each file that ends in `.1` we want a corresponding file that ends in `.3`.
type3_files:=$(type1_files:%.1=%.3)

all: $(type3_files)

# For each file that ends in `.1` we want a corresponding file that ends in `.2`.
type2_files:=$(type1_files:%.1=%.2)

# All files that end in `.2` are explicit targets to which this rule applies.
$(type2_files): %.2: %.1
    touch $@

%.3: %.2
    touch $@
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! I was already creating an explicit list of all type1 and type3 files (using `$(shell find ...)` etc. and now I just added a similarly constructed list of type2 files. I was already using a default target similar to your `all` target --- guess this is a habit common to many old C/C++ programmers :-) (either of which I've barely touched in a decade or so...)

Comment: Glad to help. I've edited my answer to bring it in line with your edited question and to fix a mistake I made in the last code snippet in my answer. You probably were not tripped by my mistake, but I'm mentioning it in case you want to look again.

Comment: Understood what you're referring to. Since I already had a list of all type1 file (size > 0, not matchig tmp*.1 etc.), I didn't trip over your typo without even realizing it was there :-).

Answer (score 0):

The following works as you expect:

```
type2 : type1
    @echo building $@ from $<
    touch $@

type3 : type2
    @echo building $@ from $<
    touch $@
```

Result:

```
$ touch type1
$ make type3
building type2 from type1
touch type2
building type3 from type2
touch type3
$ rm type2
$ make type3
building type2 from type1
touch type2
building type3 from type2
touch type3
```

Make should not treat `type2` as intermediate unless you tell it to, so your example doesn't exhibit the problem. Try to make a test case that does.